Code highlighting with Markdown, Pygments and CodeHiliteExtension in Django. Regular code blocks work nice, but inline code like `print("hi")` doesn't
I have a problem with Markdown, Pygments and CodeHiliteExtension in Django. I have a blog post written in Markdown, then I have a save function like that:
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Convert Markdown to HTML with syntax highlighting
        self.text_html = markdown.markdown(
            str(self.text_markdown),
            extensions=[
                "extra",
                "fenced_code",
                CodeHiliteExtension(linenums=False, css_class="codehilite", pygments_style="lightbulb"),
            ],
        )
        self.preview_html = markdown.markdown(
            str(self.preview_markdown),
            extensions=[
                "extra",
                "fenced_code",
                CodeHiliteExtension(linenums=False, css_class="codehilite", pygments_style="lightbulb"),
            ],
        )

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

It works nicely - I mean it's highlighting a full Mardown code blocks with all syntax like that:
/```python
/print("hi")
/```
(without the forward slash, I used it as an escape character for the post formatting).
But the inline code like that - ``print("hi")` is not working.
I tried to use variations of pymdownx.inlinehilite in extensions but I wasn't able to make it work. After some googling I found this - https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/inlinehilite/ And right now I am able to get inline code to highlight properly by using regex and manually adding missing characters like - ":::language mycode" but it's of course far from the clean solution.
I was also looking into prism.js (which works well) but I wanted to avoid using additional JavaScript. But maybe it will be cleaner after all?
So I wanted to ask you about a nicer way to force Pygments to work with both regular code blocks and inline or some better alternatives?

As the developer of the CodeHiliteExtension I can state affirmatively that the extension does not support highlighting code spans. This is an intentional decision (which has been discussed elsewhere) and we have no plans to change it. If you want to highlight code spans you will need to use a different extension. However, tool recommendations are off-topic here.

I understand, thank you for your answer. Just for completeness sake - I used this - https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/inlinehilite/ I wrote simple function that is additionally parsing my MarkDown and leveraging inlinehilite syntax.
